# Error logs dont show when running on device and XMLParseError

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, ipad, ios4

Could anyone tell me how i can enable the log functionality when running a project from xcode on a device? When i run it on the simulator i get all my NSLog statements but when i run it on an ipad i dont. Any idea whats happening?

Also would anyone know what the following error is?

```
 Entity: line 33: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name
    if (!twttr.didPingKeynote && window.location.href.indexOf('keynoteTest') > 0
```

I get this error on the log file when i run it using a simulator. I dont get any log messages when i run on the device. - NewBie

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your device connected via USB and do you see the debugger attach in the console?

Comment: USB. Its an external device not the simulator. But now thats working i dont know how though!

Comment: If your application is singed with developer's profile then above appoach will help. But if its signed with distribution profile then you can see logs on XCode organizer console window for your application. You can also use iPhone Configuration utility to see these logs.

Comment: It's working now?  Maybe your debugger wasn't attaching or a setting was changed?